# Comparing php echo result in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a working php page checking if the table has no values.

**PHP**

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('error with db');

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
{
    echo "No points found";
}
else {

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($row);

}
```

Once the php has done its job I use the result in my JS to get the value of the data:

**JS**

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../php/courseInfo.php",
    data:{ title: stringTitle},
    success: function(response){                    
    updateChartPHP(response);
}
});
```

And the function doing the job, checking if data has JSON or is just "No points found":

```
function updateChartPHP(data) {


if (data === "No points found")
{
    alert("I'm triggered");
}
else
{
    alert("Ok");
}
}
```

Except when the data returns "No points found", it seems like the first condition (data === "No points found") is never triggered even when data is clearly "No points found". Is my approach at comparing both values wrong?

I also have tried to assign "data" to a var and then compare, isn't doing it either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend, in this type of situation, to do a console.log(data) to see what is actually in your data object

Comment: I can see the "No points found" in my console log, however it seems like there are 2 lines, the top one is empty and the bottom one returns my echo.

Comment: could it be that you are echoing something else somewhere earlier in your code?

Comment: I am not, I only have two echos in my script (the ones shown). My included php file is only a connection to my db with no echo.

Comment: Fixed it! I had my include surrounded by php tags, so there was an empty line between both php tags, and that line came with my result. I just fused them into 1 script and my echo is correct now. Thank you Anis for showing me the right way.

Comment: no worries, if this fixed your problem please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

The result from my php, after checking in my console.log was not "No points found" but

"
No Points found"

with an empty line on top. This was coming from a small script above that was encased in its own php tags. The empty line between both was returned with my result.

I just fused both of the scripts as one and it's now working.